# Can I know which class is holding a database connection?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I will try to explain what I want to know.

I have a Java web app that makes connections to a MySQL database. 
If I execute SHOW PROCESSLIST in MySQL I have rows like this:

```
id: xxx
User: xxx
Host: XXX
db: XXX
Command: Sleep
Time: 12352
State:
Info: NULL
```

I understand that each process is an open connection to the database.

To manage the connections I use a pool like this
http://www.chuidiang.com/java/mysql/BasicDataSource-Pool-Conexiones.php
(It's in Spanish but I think you see the idea)

So to "open" the connection I make something like this:

```
DataSource ds = ...;
con = ds.getConnection();
```

Internally, my class is not opening the connection; it's only getting a connection already opened by the pool.

The question is:
Can I know which class is holding (or has made `con = ds.getConnection()`) a particular connection shown in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`?

Comment: One thing to try would be to log out every time you call `ds.getConnection()` or `con.close()` and examine (or parse) the log files. You could also use a pooled connection manager like [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) that provides tracing. Neither of these will appear in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, but they may help you debug.

Comment: MySQL knows nothing about Java threads, so MySQL won't tell you. Are you asking why so many connections are open to your database? If they are idle, then they are just sitting in the pool, waiting for client code to fetch them for use.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't know, so it can't tell you.

Your Java code could tell you, by running the query `SELECT CONNECTION_ID() AS connection_id` and logging the output.  This will be the same `ID` shown in `SHOW [FULL] PROCESSLIST:`.

Note, of course, that this doesn't mean the class still holds the connection, only that it obtained it.  Sleeping threads are idle and if you're pooling, *nobody* may be holding them.  Whoever held the connection last may have already released it to the pool.

Also, remember, that sleeping threads are sleeping, so they generally aren't hurting anything, sitting there sleeping like that.  The time is time since last used for a query.

You may also find that, in the presence of a a stateful firewall between MySQL and the application, a connection is idled out of the firewall's memory due to excessive idleness (sometimes with crazy low times like 15 minutes).  The application tends to initiate most interactions with MySQL, so the application will figure out that the connection is useless (thanks to the firewall), abandon it, and get a new one when it la attempts to communicate with the server after such an idle period are rebuffed by the firewall, but the server will sit happily waiting for requests that never come.  These connections *are* wasting server resources when this happens.  Enabling TCP keepalives in the kernels of the servers will mitigate this, if it's happening.  The firewall could be part of your infrastructure that you don't realize is doing this.